# No output from a program that compiles

Tags: java, file-io

I can't wrap my head around why I get zero output... The code looks correct to me, and it compiles with no problem (except for the lack of output). I have tried with absolute path. The text file is stored in the same folder as the class. Am I missing something obvious?

```java
public class File {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String filename = "./inputD2.txt";
        readFile(filename);
        System.out.println( readFile(filename));
    }
    private static List<String> readFile(String filename) {
        List<String> records = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                records.add(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            return records;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.format("Exception occurred trying to read '%s'.", filename);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not the problem per se, but `readFile(filename);` by itself on the second line of your `main` does nothing useful.

Comment: You don't see anything, not even an error?

Comment: Is that definitely the right code because the main method throws `FileNotFoundException` but the `readFile` method catches all exceptions.  Also what is the purpose of the `format` call on the system error stream as it doesn't seem to do anything?  Suggest strip back all the exception handling to check your file actually exists.

Comment: Do you get an exception trace, or just `[]`? If you get literally zero output (no text whatsoever), that is __impossible__ given your paste - then either your java install is corrupt (unlikely), or you aren't running what you think you're running; you're running an older version of your class, for example.

Comment: While learning a programming language, it's also useful to learn about the tools. So use your IDE's debugging feature to single-step through your program, watching the variable values. Then you'll see where the program does things you didn't expect.

Comment: You named your class the same as an existing standard Java class. It could be that it's confusing the environment. It's bad practice in any case - try giving your class another name (don't forget to change the name of the source file to match).

Comment: Took away the exception handling and realized that the solution was as trivial as it gets. I was running the wrong class... I blame it on the new IDE I my professor is forcing us to use. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileReaderTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename = "F:\\Sixth_workspace\\Sampleproject\\src\\main\\resources\\try.txt";
        System.out.println("Reading from the text file" + " " + readFile(filename));

    }

    private static List<String> readFile(String filename) {

        List<String> records;
        try {
            records = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                records.add(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            return records;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.err.println("Exception occurred trying to read '%s'." + filename);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I modified your code and got the desired output. Use the full path of the text file, here

```
F:\\Sixth_workspace\\Sampleproject\\src\\main\\resources\\try.txt
```

is my full path.

Changes:

1. Changed the classname
2. Given full path of the text file
3. Using java 1.8 (above 1.5 is required)